# jboss as 7 + jersey - ClassNotFound com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.Include

Tags: jboss, jersey, maven-3, jboss7.x

I migrating project on jboss as 7 from jersey version 1.9 to 1.17 and I get the following exception:

```
12:05:48,573 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.Include due to except
ion: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.Include from [Module "deployment.ApiEar-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.ApiService-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war:ma
in" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32-ea]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32-ea]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-
redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32-ea]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32-ea]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32-ea]
```

code runs fine under 1.9. Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

what could cause such an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is related to the fact that Jersey was changed quite a bit from version 1.9 to 1.10; namely there was a big change to Servlet functionality. You can read more here: [Jersey 1.10 released](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/jersey_1_10_is_released)
As far as your problem goes, I think you simply missing some dependencies. I know I had to add the following to my .pom file:

```
        <!-- Jersey 1.17 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end Jersey 1.17 dependencies -->
```